# Program to count the number of words in a sentence above the minimium letter requirements

Tags: java, string, io, word-count

This program asks you for the minimum length of a word and a sentence. The purpose of the program is to count the number of words in a sentence that meet the letter length requirements. Can someone please help me with my counter, the word count won't increase.

```
public class wordcount {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      int length = IO.readInt();
      String sentence = IO.readString();
      int full = sentence.length();
      int wordcount = 0;

      for(int i = 0; i == length; i++){
         if(Character.isLetter(sentence.charAt(i)))
            wordcount= wordcount + 1;
      }
      System.out.print(wordcount);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your for loop: -

```
for(int i = 0; i == length; i++)  // Code in this loop will not run even once.
```

To: -

```
for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0; i == length; i++){
```

Your `for` loop exits immediately.  `i` is certainly not equal to `length`; it's `0`.

Answer (score 0):

In for loops, there are three expressions:

- Initialization
- Termination
- Increment

Your initialization and increment are fine, but your termination expression doesn't make any sense if you're wanting to iterate. As the others have stated, changing your termination expression to `i < length` will correct this, and allow you to loop through `length` number of times because `i` will iterate until it is greater than `length`, at which point the termination expression will be fulfilled and the program will move on.